# Why `float` function is slower than multiplying by 1.0?

Tags: python, optimization, python-internals

I understand that this could be argued as a non-issue, but I write software for HPC environments, so this 3.5x speed increase actually makes a difference.

```
In [1]: %timeit 10 / float(98765)            
1000000 loops, best of 3: 313 ns per loop

In [2]: %timeit 10 / (98765 * 1.0)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 80.6 ns per loop
```

I used `dis` to have a look at the code, and I assume `float()` will be slower as it requires a function call (unfortunately I couldn't `dis.dis(float)` to see what it's actually doing).

I guess a second question would be when should I use `float(n)` and when should I use `n * 1.0`?

Comment: Aside from the difference of two dict lookups (global and builtin) and a function call, the second one probably gets [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) applied.

Comment: Without the constant folding (i.e. when I replace `98765` with a variable) that shows much closer result, `float` is still slightly slower. As for why you certainly may want to use `float` is unified conversion like `float('1.0')`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because Peep hole optimizer optimizes it by precalculating the result of that multiplication

```
import dis
dis.dis(compile("10 / float(98765)", "<string>", "eval"))

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (float)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (98765)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             13 RETURN_VALUE        

dis.dis(compile("10 / (98765 * 1.0)", "<string>", "eval"))

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 (98765.0)
              6 BINARY_DIVIDE       
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

It stores the result of `98765 * 1.0` in the byte code as a constant value. So, it just has to load it and divide, where as in the first case we have to call the function.

We can see that even more clearly like this

```
print compile("10 / (98765 * 1.0)", "<string>", "eval").co_consts
# (10, 98765, 1.0, 98765.0)
```

Since the value is pre-calculated during the compile time itself, second one is faster.

**Edit:** As pointed out by [Davidmh in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983625/why-is-10-float98765-3-5x-slower-than-10-98765-1-0/22983997?noredirect=1#comment35098851_22983997),

> And the reason why it is not also optimising away the division is because its behaviour depends on flags, like `from __future__ import division` and also because of `-Q` flag.

Quoting [the comment from the actual peephole optimizer code for Python 2.7.9](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/648dcafa7e5f/Python/peephole.c#l110),

```c
        /* Cannot fold this operation statically since
           the result can depend on the run-time presence
           of the -Qnew flag */
```

Comment: And the reason why it is not also optimising away the division is because its behaviour depends on flags, like `from __future__ import division`.

Comment: @Davidmh Thanks :) I included that also in the answer.

Comment: if you `a = 98765` and then test `10/float(a)` and `10/(a*1.0)` I still get the 2x speed difference, but the compiled code doesn't seem to be subject to constant folding.

Comment: I understand that the purpose of `float()` (calling the `__float__` magic method) is a lot different than multiplying by 1.0, but I often see python 2 integer division taught as a/float(b) (or by `from __future__ import division`), and I was trying to work out if there's a reason here beyond `float()` being able to work on arbitrary types that have a `__float__` method

Comment: Given that this compiler does not optimize away the division, the OP should really precompute 0.0010125044f

Comment: Now you mention it it's odd that the compiler precomputes `98765 * 1.0` but not the `10 / ...`

Comment: @JasonP The division can be controlled by flags which are not set in the program. That is why, it doesn't optimize that.

Comment: Under Python 3, it *does* optimize the whole thing into a single `LOAD_CONST`, because `/` is always true division in 3.x.  Of course, at that point, you may as well just write `10 / 98765` and be done with it.