# Why is integer divisions not optimised when compiling to bytecode?

Tags: python, bytecode, python-internals

First, let me show a experiment I do:

```
In [69]: dis.dis(lambda : 4 / 2 +  1.5 * 2 + (4 - 2))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (4)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
              6 BINARY_DIVIDE       
              7 LOAD_CONST               4 (3.0)
             10 BINARY_ADD          
             11 LOAD_CONST               5 (2)
             14 BINARY_ADD          
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see in the output of `dis.dis`, `1.5 * 2` and `4 - 2` get compiled to `LOAD_CONST` instead of two `LOAD_CONST` followed by a binary operation.

But `4 / 2` is not replaced with something like `LOAD_CONST 4 (2)`.

I wonder why is division left out in the optimisation.

The version of Python I use is 2.7.5.

BTW, it seems that in Python 3, functions like this get better optimizations, here's what I see:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda : 4 / 2 +  1.5 * 2 + (4 - 2))
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               8 (7.0)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because division can be controlled by the following factors

1. [`python -Q`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#miscellaneous-options) command line argument
2. [`from __future__ import division`](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

which will not be available to the peephole optimizer at the compile time.

This is explained in the source code of [peephole](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/peephole.c#l110)

Comment: Hehe, that's serendipitous that this question was asked shortly after having discussed this in the chatroom! :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup. Also, I [answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22983997/1903116) two days ago :-)

Comment: Ah! That's why you brought it up! :-)

Comment: Yup, I knew that it optimizes the multiplication (thats obvious from the bytecode), but I couldn't reason why division wasn't. That's why I asked you, meanwhile went through the peephole code and figured out whats going on :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye What are some good resources about this `peephole` thing?

Comment: @satoru Actually I read the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/peephole.c), but Peep Hole optimizer is a general concept in the compiler design.