# Function definition in Python takes a lot of time

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

Why is python trying to calculate the value of `p` during definition? It takes ages to define this function.

```
def f():
    raise Exception('Some error')
    p = 2322111239**42322222334923492304923

print 'Defined!'
```

Also if the value of `p` is being calculated during definition, why is it possible to define this function without errors?

```
def f():
    return 4
    p = 11/0
```

This one obviously works fine because constants are not involved:

```
def f():
    raise Exception('Some error')
    x=42322222334923492304923
    p = 2322111239**x

print 'Defined!'
```

Comment: PS: Try to define the top function in your IDLE. It will crash :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the peephole optimizer:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/peephole.c#L88

See in particular lines [104-106](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/peephole.c#L104-L106):

```
case BINARY_POWER:
    newconst = PyNumber_Power(v, w, Py_None);
    break;
```

The intention is to speed up runtime execution of the function, trading-off for a slower definition time when the module is imported. The idea is you only need to compile the code for the function once, but you may need to call it many times, and the outcome of an exponentiation binop for two constants is not going to change so it needn't be recomputed every time.

*Note:* In Python 3, [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) has moved into the new AST optimizer in [`ast_opt.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ast_opt.c#L227), `peephole.c` is gone. The code now has [safeguards](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5c7b38f5ebbc84b5b80192db1743d3e1cdcf4c5/Python/ast_opt.c#L100-L134) in place to prevent the overly-eager optimizations that could cause as a slow or memory-hungry parse/compile step as shown in this question.

Comment: Interesting since, look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#id3

Comment: Because that is documenting _python_ (language), not cpython (implementation).

Comment: @anon it's not actually __executing__ the function, it's just calculating the value of the constant inside it.

Comment: I'm not saying wim is wrong. (I didn't down vote, in fact I upvoted), but @dano: you could argue the samething about doc strings... I just find the doc misleading.

Comment: This is actually incorrect. If you look at the source code referenced, then the same thing SHOULD happen with any other literal; i.e., try any other one of those case statements and it should also immediately execute. These are binary functions. Try `def f(): x=1/0` and that does not throw an error at compile time.

Comment: @dawg it does throw an error at compile time, but it is handled in cpython.  error handling for that case starts at line 209  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cd87afe18ff8/Python/peephole.c#l209

Comment: and in python 2.7, the fold is not attempted for case BINARY_DIVIDE.    http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/eabff2a97b5b/Python/peephole.c#l110  (related question about that -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031282/why-is-integer-divisions-not-optimised-when-compiling-to-bytecode)

Answer (score 7):

This feature of the interpreter is called `constant folding` (see [here](http://cfbolz.de/draft/trace-time-computation.html) for some nice information). There exist several issues addressing even too aggressive constant folding. Similar issues can arise for memory as well, where a lot of memory is allocated and directly thrown away again (see [here](http://bugs.python.org/issue21074)).

Answer (score 3):

Let's try a more reasonable number:

```
>>> def f():
...    p=123**45
...
```

If you use [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to view the byte codes, you can see that the value for p is being defined BEFORE the function is called:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (11110408185131956285910790587176451918559153212268021823629073199866111001242743283966127048043)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (p)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: `import dis` then `dis.dis(f)`

Comment: @wim: It's an answer. Your comment was also an answer.

Comment: I disagree, the question was "Why does Python do this" and not "Is Python doing this". And it is an intresting question ;)

Comment: No, at best it just verifies the OP's claim.  The question was "Why is python trying to calculate the value of p during definition?"

Comment: Yes that's what I thought but WHY is Python trying to do that? I mean is there any reason why they made Python to do that?

Comment: So it doesn't have to do it during execution.

Comment: @kindall: That would not make much sense, as it is not even clear that it is ever called. Therefore, it might happen that you do it all for nothing. Or am I missing a point?

Comment: Most programmers are not in the habit of defining functions that are never called.

Comment: As soon you import a library most functions are likley to be never called. You can, however, argue that most programs would not do p = 2322111239**42322222334923492304923 ;)

Comment: The result would be stored in the compiled `.pyc` file, so the import would take a long time only the *first* time it was used. In any case, if it's really a problem, you can simply define `p` equal to the result of that multiplication, rather than doing the multiplication!

Comment: This does not answer the question, it's just a different way of showing what the OP already showed in the question ("python is trying to calculate the value of p during definition"). Recommend deletion.